# Using Angular with 2 text input - ngx-bootstrap datepickers, they both update each other

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I have 2 different input textboxes, but clicking on one and selecting a date ends up updating BOTH,  WHY??

```
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="HearingDate" name="HearingDate" id="HearingDate" [minDate]="minDate"
      [maxDate]="maxDate" #dp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="bsValue" [bsConfig]="dpConfig">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="ReporterDate" name="ReporterDate" id="ReporterDate" [minDate]="minDate"
      [maxDate]="maxDate" #xdp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="bsValue" [bsConfig]="dpConfig">
  </div>
```

Comment: Try using different `bsValue` like `[(bsValue)]="bsValue1"` and `[(bsValue)]="bsValue2"`

Comment: I always thought the banana in a box had to be ngModel , I didn't realize that was something "built in" to the dependency? right?   Should I use ngModel or bsValue ?    or both  ?

Comment: Can't say exactly. I'm not very familiar with ngx-bootstrap api:) https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: Should I use [(bsValue)]  or  [(ngModel)]  ?    or both